# Mockito ArgumentMatchers.refEq Exclude Nested Field

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to exclude a nested field for my `doReturn().when()` statement.

Consider two classes like these:

```
class User {
    private String name;
    private String lastName;
    private Address address;
}

class Address {
    private City city;
    private String street;
}

class City {
    private String state;
    private String mayor;
}
```

I am trying to write some unit tests and I need to mock the method that takes a `User` instance as a parameter.

```
private LocalDateTime getLastLogin(User user){
//whatever...
}
```

I can mock this method by passing `any()` for the `User` parameter however I want to be sure same object is sent to the method.

This method does not accept the parameter as the same even though all the properties are same.

```
doReturn(time).when(userService).getLastLogin(ArgumentMatchers.refEq(user));
```

However If i exclude the Address than it works perfectly fine.

```
doReturn(time).when(userService).getLastLogin(ArgumentMatchers.refEq(user,"address"));
```

But I don't want to exclude the `address` even if I have to exclude something I want to exclude `city`.

I've tried a notation similar to the Lombok but it doesn't work.

```
doReturn(time).when(userService).getLastLogin(ArgumentMatchers.refEq(user,"address.city"));
```

Is there any way to exclude an nested field with mockito argument matchers ?

Comment: Maybe you should implements equals in your class. 
Then you could use the matchers eq()

Comment: @Ruokki Thank you for your advice however, I did not create these classes. They're generated from a WSDL, so I do not want to modify the generated classes.

Answer (score 0):

To first directly answer the question:
To my knowledge `refEq` doesn't offer that capability.

> however I want to be sure same object is sent to the method.

That being said if this ^ is what your end goal is then I'd just mock more openly with `any(User.class)` and then achieve that goal with specific assertions against the call value of `getLastLogin` using `verify`. I've dealt with this issue before and this is how I got past it.

You can use `ArgumentCaptor` to extract the argument and then pick it apart asserting against however much or little you want against both the top level `User` and also any nested parts like `Address`.

```java
final ArgumentCaptor argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(User.class);
verify(userService).getLastLogin(argumentCaptor.capture());
final User user = (User) argumentCaptor.getValue();
final Address address = user.getAddress();
// do whatever assertions you want
```

You might be interested in `org.hamcrest.beans.SamePropertyValuesAs.samePropertyValuesAs`(http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/beans/SamePropertyValuesAs.html) which will provide equivalent `refEq` behavior in assertions.

Also I might add that something I've personally been practicing is trying to "mock openly assert specifically". It tends to lead to less code mocking and makes it harder for a dev to accidentally mess up a test where they might change something which wouldn't affect the asserted end value.